Error building module DBD::SQLite on Debian Gnu/Linux, sqlite3.c
I am trying to install the CPAN module DBD::SQLite and I am getting a strange failure. The compilation of several C files into object code goes fine, and then when we hit sqlite3.c the compilation just hangs. The abbreviated command is:
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -c  [...]  sqlite3.c

I'd like confirmation if anyone else could try it; maybe someone using perlbrew?
Here is some version information:

gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
DBD-SQLite-1.76
Perl v5.40.0


Are you sure it hangs? It's a 9MB (!) file, so it may take some time to compile.

I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic. If gcc just hangs, it's a bug in gcc, and this is not the place to report it.

@ikegami: fair enough. robertklep: yes, and I tried multiple times and the last time I left it running overnight.

Did you try to strace the command?

You have to use strace -f so that child processes are also traced. On my system, that permanently produces output. You can also try to change option -O2 to -O0 to switch off optimization. That will trigger a warning because _FORTIFY_SOURCE is used but I guess you can ignore that for now.
